# How do change value of Image in report?

Tags: c#, winforms, report

i am using winForm C#.
i have created one parameter named 'path' and assigned source as external and value how to set dynamical or in his property ?
i have error on report.rdlc "The enable externalimages property has not been set for this report "

```
 this.pedidosTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = con.MysqlConnect();
 //for external image
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
 ReportParameter parm = new ReportParameter("path");
 parm.Visible = true;
 parm.Name = "path";
 parm.Values.Add("File:////C:\\logo.jpg");
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parm);
 this.reportViewer1.Refresh();
```

[image]

where is problem please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the placeholder for the image, you have to change the property `Source` in `External`

Comment: I don't understand: it works for the default value but when you are trying to change it with the `ReportParameter` didn't works?

Comment: Seems that your path need to include the string `file:///` so you need to pass this: `file:///C:\logo.jpg`. [Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/160037/How-to-Pass-Image-in-Microsoft-Report)

Comment: Ok now I understand: click on the down arrow, select `Expression`, in the `Category` select `Parameters`, in the `Values` double click on your parameter's name and press `Ok`. Or... just copy what you have wrote in the `Tooltip` property

Comment: now i have error that parameter path is missing a value ? value i already defined under code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20003/discussion-between-user142320-and-nanny)

Comment: my problem resolved. first i change photo format as *.png then i chang code like this.

Comment: reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
ReportParameter[] parm = new ReportParameter[1];
parm[0] = new ReportParameter( "parm","file:////C:\\logo.png",false);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[]{ parm[0]});
this.reportViewer1.Refresh();

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Enable External Images

```
// Set RDL file
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdl";

// Enable External Images
reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
```

And you must write the address of the image as:

```
File://C:\\logo.jpg
```

(Only 2 slashes after File:)